# I need help figuring out what i did wrong

Tags: java

I can't get the hours or day into a number but Zero. What I am i doing wrong?
I need to get minutes into hours and days.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int minutes=0,hours=0,days=0, years=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of mintues");
        minutes= input.nextInt();

        minutes += (hours*60);
        hours += (days*1440);
        days += (years*365);
        System.out.println("The amount of Hours in minute is: "+hours + "hours");
        System.out.println("The amunt of Days is in mintue is: " +days +"days");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're multiplying everything by 0.

Comment: This isn't a question about Java.  It's a question about math.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is wrong. You need something like below(untested):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minutes=0,hours=0,days=0, years=0;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of mintues");
    minutes= input.nextInt();

    hours = (minutes/60);
    days = (minutes/1440);
    System.out.println("The amount of Hours in minute is: "+hours + "hours");
    System.out.println("The amunt of Days is in mintue is: " +days +"days");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the 0 instead of the value of minute. Please refer below:

```
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int minutes=0,hours=0,days=0, years=0;
            System.out.println("Enter the number of mintues");

            //get minute
            minutes= input.nextInt();
            //calculate hours
            hours = minutes / 60;
            //calculate days
            days = hours/24;
            //calculate year
            years = days/365;
            System.out.println("The amount of Hours in minute is: "+hours + "hours");
            System.out.println("The amunt of Days is in mintue is: " +days +"days");
```

Hope this help.